# Trigger.io & Parse push notifications don't work when I switch to production certificate

Tags: ios, parsing, push-notification, trigger.io, parse-platform

Using Trigger.io and Parse - I'm trying to submit my app to the iOS store. I got parse push notifications working on iOS (and Android) using a development provisioning profile. I switched to an ad-hoc production certificate, and now the same code gets this error:

```
TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object
```

For this line: *(In reality it's more complex but I stripped it down to this line and it still doesn't work.)*

```
forge.event.messagePushed.addListener(function (msg) {
    forge.logging.log(JSON.stringify(msg));
  });
```

Things I've done:

- Checked to make sure the parse module was set up in config.json with the right keys
- Check to make sure I'm using the new correct provisioning profile to build the app
- Used the correct .p12 file for the parse certificate.
- Made sure I'm subscribed to the correct channel.

What am I doing wrong?

***edit:*** Cleaned up code for more clarity.

***edit:*** Check out the comments for more info. 
It might help to mention that when I run

```
forge.event.messagePushed.addListener(function (msg) {
    alert(JSON.stringify(msg));
});
```

It returns an alert (with message: "undefined") right away.

Comment: This is a bug, thanks for reporting it - we have recreated it. The problem is that the callback function is called right away with an empty message as soon as forge.event.messagePushed.addListener is called. You can avoid the problem by adding a check for an empty message for now and we'll report back here with a fix.

Comment: Thanks Amir. That's quite helpful. This was driving me mad!

Answer (score 1):

In your question you are actually talking about two different things.

The `forge.notification` module has nothing to do with the push notifications provided by the Parse integration. The former can be used to send a notification to the user's phone which is triggered by the app and **while the app is opened**.

In my opinion this is not extremely useful to send push notifications, as those are usually triggered when something happens **while the user is not currently using the app**. Thats where the Parse integration comes into play. The correct module for this is called `forge.partners.parse`.

You can trigger push notifications manually from the Parse Web Interface. Go to the Push section of your app (URL: `https://parse.com/apps/<your app>/push_notifications` ) and choose `+ Send a push` on the top. There you can target, customize and send your push. Hope this helps.

If you want to automatically trigger push notifications based on certain events (e.g. on your backend server), you should have a look at the [Parse Push Notification Guide](https://parse.com/docs/push_guide#top/REST).

Comment: Thanks Patrick. I think it's my fault for confusing the issue - Forget forge.notification. The same problem happens with alerts, forge.logging.log, or even nothing at all. The line with forge.event.messagePushed.addListener throws the error.

Comment: Also, I had push notifications working before on a dev certificate. The only change is the move to development. Problem is, I think I've ticked off all the boxes needed when switching certificates, and it's still not working.

Comment: Oh ok, I misunderstood you. Does the JS error throw when starting the app or when receiving a notification? Does the notification show up on the device at all?

Comment: Thanks. The error shows up when starting the app, and the notification isn't showing up at all.

Comment: I could imagine you are adding the event listener to early in the code, but that wouldn't explain why it worked earlier. Could you try to add the listener at a later point? You should also double-check if you really uploaded the correct production profiles and if push is enabled on this profile in your iOS Provisioning Portal.

Comment: And when I ran the listener code in the catalyst debugger, I got an alert (with an undefined message) right away.

Comment: Push is enabled on this profile in the provisioning center. I downloaded the certificate associated with it, opened it in keychain access, exported the .p12 file, and uploaded that file to parse. I stripped out all the listener code and tried to add it into the code using the Catalyst debugger. It didn't return the error then, but subscribing to a channel returns a 100 error.